# Linear dependence or independence $\{ x,|x|\}$ over field $F=R,$ set of real numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

Linear dependence or independence $\{ x,|x|\}$ over field $F=R,$ set of real numbers.

$|x|$ curve is V shaped curve while x is linear with slope $45^o$. When both curves are parallel or same, then linearly dependent else linearly independent.

Pls correct me with respect to following:

1)$\{ x,|x|\}$ is Linearly independent if domain is R (correct me if i am wrong in these statements)
2)$\{ x,|x|\}$ is Linearly independent if domain is $[-1,1]$
3)$\{ x,|x|\}$ is Linearly **independent** if domain is $[-\infty, 0]$ **---> is this correct???**
4)$\{ x,|x|\}$ is Linearly dependent if domain is $[0,\infty]$

Comment: As far as I can tell your only mistake is 3). They are dependent.

Comment: yes this is solution given in textbook. But i am not convinced. If domain is negative x-zxis, curve |x| slopes at 135 degree(2nd quadrant) and x is sloping at 45 deg (4th quadrant). There is no parallism or intersection. THen 
 **independent right**?

Comment: You idea of linear dependence seems to come from "arrow-like" vectors. Two such "arrows" are linear dependent if they are parallel or anti-parallel. You cannot apply this to functions directly, especially not to their *graphs*! For example: are $\{1,x,x^2,x(1-x)\}$ linearly independent? The question you should ask is whether there are numbers $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R$ so that $$\alpha x+\beta|x|=0$$ for all $x$ in the domain. I recommend restating the *true* definition of linear independence in your question.

Comment: So for any -a in negative real axis, the above equation becomes $\alpha (-a) + \beta (a) = 0 \implies \alpha = \beta. So 1.x=-(1).|x| $

Got it. Thanks.